# Strange character in vim airline

Tags: vim, vim-airline

[image]

I don't know how to remove the character after the `master` branch (The inverted `E`)

Comment: not exists symbol

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That symbol is the notexists symbol and means the currently edited file does not yet exist in your repository.

Comment: Nice, here's some extra background info if anyone else is curious: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2204/index.htm